# equivalent of rails' "devise" for a python micro-framework?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, django

I have a new project that requires a user authentication system... I've done this in PHP, but I have the desire to use Python this time around, and I *really* don't want to hand-roll all the forms and controller logic.

I seem to remember something equivalent in Djano, but I'd rather avoid having to learn a monolithic framework. I'd also like to avoid having to learn Ruby.

Comment: Django is (a) actually pretty light-weight (b) not monolithic.

Comment: Django lightweight?  Not when compared to Flask or web.py.

Answer (score 3):

If you want you can use a WSGI middleware and plug it in to handle auth, there are a few modules for this [repoze.who](http://docs.repoze.org/who/1.0/) <strike>and [AuthKit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/AuthKit)</strike> comes to mind. For flask there is also [Flask-Principal](http://packages.python.org/Flask-Principal/). It's also not particularly hard to roll your own.

Comment: 2010-06-04: AuthKit is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 0):

AuthLib has an [example OAuth2 server](https://github.com/authlib/example-oauth2-server) that works as advertised right after you clone it and follow the directions under "Take a quick look".